# Inequalities of high level

Tags: inequality

For positive reals $a,b,c$ prove
$$\frac{a+b-2c}{b+c} +\frac{b+c-2a}{c+a} +
\frac{c+a-2b}{a+b}\geq 0$$

I proved this if these $a,b,c$ were sides of a triangle but could not proceed further

Comment: What is Ravi's substitution?pls clarify it and then I hope I can solve this question

Comment: can u write some important points of this inequality. I have 2g internet connection which is opening this link very slow

Comment: @G-man The substitution you mention would have been useful to prove if $a, b, c$ where sides of a triangle.  For all positive reals, it is not at all obvious how that would work.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  Note that
$$\prod_{cyc}(b+c) \sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b-2c}{b+c} = \sum_{cyc} a(a-c)^2$$